# Can I use a data URL when importing a web component template?

Tags: web-component

You can import a web component using the following syntax:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-component.html"/>
```

Can I make the `href` a data URL?

(I will report back if I succeed in doing so).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? Something like document.URL?

If so, the way to do this inside of your `my-component.html` would be something like this (it's need to in a `<script>` from your component's html):

```
var url = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.URL;
// which would be "http://localhost/my-component.html"
```